# What does the sorted by 'most frequent' search filter mean on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search

Does it mean it is sorted by the most viewed questions recently?

Is there a way to search questions based on how much recent activity they have, to gauge how popular they are currently (highest score just brings up whatever was the most popular in the past; I'm looking specifically for recent activity statistics)?